# Update Project dll files on published project

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have two .NET C# projects. One for CRUD operation displaying the web pages (MVC) and the other to generate reports and to download them as excel and word documents.

Once published:-

1. Is it possible to just modify the dll for document generation project without republishing the entire project?
2. Will this affect the primary project since the reference was made to the old project dll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes you can , assuming that you didn't change the `Views` or any
   other files that the project depends on so you have to upload these
   files too.
2. Same here , you have to be sure that the modifications
   doesn't have effect on others files like adding / changing resources
   used by the other projects or files out side `dll` code